# Add remove events

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, dom-events

I recently read a tutorial on cross-browser event handling... [Cross-Browser Event Handling...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff728624.aspx)

I've adapted some practises from the tutorial to a generalised function that's floating around like so...

```
function isHostMethod(object, property) {
    var type = typeof object[property];
    return type === "function" || (type === "object" && !! object[property]) || type === "unknown";
}

var events = {
    add: (function() {
        if (isHostMethod(this, 'addEventListener')) {
            return function(element, type, handler) {
                element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
            };
        } else if (isHostMethod(this, 'attachEvent')) {
            return function(element, type, handler) {
                element.attachEvent('on' + type, function() {
                    handler.call(element, window.event);
                });
            };
        } else {
            return function(element, type, handler) {
                element['on' + type] = handler;
            };
        }
    }()),
    remove: (function() {
        if (isHostMethod(this, 'removeEventListener')) {
            return function(element, type, handler) {
                element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
            };
        } else if (isHostMethod(this, 'detachEvent')) {
            return function(element, type, handler) {
                element.detachEvent('on' + type, function() {
                    handler.call(element, window.event);
                });
            };
        } else {
            return function(element, type, handler) {
                element['on' + type] = null;
           };
       }
    }())
};
```

usage:

```
var img_wrap = document.getElementById('img_wrap'),
    img = img_wrap.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    img_amount = img.length;

function do_stuff() {
    //
    //do stuff - update preloaded percentage, etc. 
    //
    events.remove(this, 'load', do_stuff);
}

for (var i = 0; i < img_amount; i += 1) {
    events.add(img[i], 'load', do_stuff);
}
```

**This is what I'm curious about...**
1. Is the 'isHostMethod' function necessary?
2. The tutorial warns about memory leaks and outlines an addition function for avoiding them using 'unique ids' as a reference to each element... This hasn't been included... Maybe I'm overseeing something but I don't think it's necessary in my case... *OR* should I be concerned?

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgXaN/2/)
warning: the images are huge, take a while to download, lots of bandwidth, etc.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with cross-browser issues like this is to use a library like jQuery or MooTools. Their authors have addressed most of compatibility issues so you don't have to.

Comment: @Barmar        Thanks for the suggestion. I would normally use jQuery BUT I'm using this for a single page site, for a fellow student's/ friend's art portfolio. I'm avoiding jQuery cuz I feel that it's overkill to include a whole library for the support of one event listener 'load'. Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: In that case, you probably don't have to worry about memory leaks, either.

Comment: @Barmar        This is true, your totally right but I'm a javascript noob and I'm trying to learn things the 'right' way. Learning to code 'javaScript' while excluding memory leaks would be beneficial. I've read several blogs/tutorials on memory leaks but I can't identify to anything in my code causing any, perhaps noob oversight? Probably noob oversight...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > 1.Is the 'isHostMethod' function necessary?

*Nop*, unless you persist to support IE6,7 and 8. Every modern browser uses `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` now.

So I guess this is not acceptable, that's why people uses libs like mootools and jQuery. And they will take care that for you.

> > 2.The tutorial warns about memory leaks and outlines an addition function for avoiding them using 'unique ids' as a reference to each element... This hasn't been included... Maybe I'm overseeing something but I don't think it's necessary in my case or should I be concerned about memory leaks?

It's depends. If you're going to build a Gmail, Stackoverflow, FB, G+ or Twitter, memory leak do matter a lot, as the pages on these sites barely refresh, and will live for a long time.

But if you just want to make a web page, attach some events and people will click on a link and move to next. As the context will be freed when they move on, even you do leak some memory, it won't cause any trouble (though I think you should try to avoid it, but it's not a *must*.)

And here is a [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-memleak/) from IBM on how to avoid memory leak (which is a little out-of-date, and some patterns are no longer leak memory.) It may help you.

And in practice, you can always profile memory usage using Chrome's inspector, which is a very powerful tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've read several blogs/tutorials on memory leaks but I havnt come accross the one by IBM, gonna check it out now... Appreciate it!